# how to track How many times the user opened the app in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, analytics, tracking

as mentioned in the title above, I want to know how many times a user opens the app (Flutter app) within a given timeframe (weekly, monthly, etc), I suspect that Firebase Analytics might be able to do this, so if that's the case, how do I approach it?
Please Help if you could, I'm sort of tired of searching.